# Servlet : Login Attempt failed to decrement

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have been facing this problem, I know this is a frequent question asked throughout but the problem have not been rectified with the research i did.

The problem I face is that I created logic that, if the same username will attempt to log in 2 times, it should decrement the number of attempts. But, it always stays at no attempt 2.

I did basically this: I tried using HttpSession to count the number of visit on page but failed. Cause I feel, that whenever I redirect it to my login page. It will just restart the session.

My initial plan is that, in my JDBC code, it will block `user_acc == 1`, if user tries to log in more than 3 times. But looking at the major problems I'm facing, I decide to come with basic logic which just take in username from input field without connecting to database. After I rectify this, I will modify to connect it to my database.

Any help will really be appreciated.

```
String name =  request.getParameter("username");
String pass = request.getParameter("password");
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
int login_attempt = 3;

HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
session.setAttribute("name",name);  
String sessionName = (String) session.getAttribute("name");

if(name.equals("scott")){

    if(pass.equals("abc"))
    {
    pw.println(("Success"));
    pw.println(sessionName);
    }
    else {
        login_attempt = login_attempt - 1;
        if(login_attempt < 3 && sessionName.equals(name)){
            pw.println(" You have this try " + login_attempt + " : " + sessionName);
        } else if(login_attempt == 0 && sessionName.equals(name)){
            pw.println("Please contact admin for as your account is blocked");
        }

    }
}
```

**SOLVED**
For the benefit of others, I have solved this problem

```
int loginAttempt;
if (session.getAttribute("loginCount") == null) {
    // This will first set login count to zero
    session.setAttribute("loginCount", 0);
    loginAttempt = 0;
} else {
    loginAttempt = (Integer) session.getAttribute("loginCount");
    // System.out.println("How many attempt " + loginAttempt);
}

if (loginAttempt == 3) {
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);

    System.out.println(("game over"));
    pw.println("No more attempt please call admin\n\n");
    pw.println("<br/> \n\n\n\n\n\n         left for interval");

} else {
    System.out.println("How many attempt " + loginAttempt);
    // loginAttempt = loginAttempt + 1;
    loginAttempt++;
    int allowLogin = 3 - loginAttempt;



    session.setAttribute("message", "loginAttempt= " + loginAttempt
            + ". Invalid username or password. You have " + allowLogin + " attempts remaining.");
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}

if (isTrue != false) {
    pw.println("Username does not exist in database");
}

session.setAttribute("loginCount", loginAttempt);
pw.println("Invalid users");
```

Comment: This code is incomplete. I guess is in some class. Variable login_attempt is local and is restoreved every shot

Comment: I dont quite get it for comparing the username to store it as session and when it redirect to login page with incorrect password. it will recognize username based on failed login and decrement the attempt accordingly . any idea?

Comment: Nted.  i just did . :)@Mark Rotteveel

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED For the benefit of others, I have solved this problem**

```
int loginAttempt;
if (session.getAttribute("loginCount") == null) {
    // This will first set login count to zero
    session.setAttribute("loginCount", 0);
    loginAttempt = 0;
} else {
    loginAttempt = (Integer) session.getAttribute("loginCount");
    // System.out.println("How many attempt " + loginAttempt);
}

if (loginAttempt == 3) {
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);

    System.out.println(("game over"));
    pw.println("No more attempt please call admin\n\n");
    pw.println("<br/> \n\n\n\n\n\n         left for interval");

} else {
    System.out.println("How many attempt " + loginAttempt);
    // loginAttempt = loginAttempt + 1;
    loginAttempt++;
    int allowLogin = 3 - loginAttempt;



    session.setAttribute("message", "loginAttempt= " + loginAttempt
            + ". Invalid username or password. You have " + allowLogin + " attempts remaining.");
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}

if (isTrue != false) {
    pw.println("Username does not exist in database");
}

session.setAttribute("loginCount", loginAttempt);
pw.println("Invalid users");
```